# mysql2.rb:2:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, file, load

I continue running into the same wall.

> C:\Users\red19_000\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
>
> ```
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in 'require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in '<top (required)>'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'block (2 levels) in require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in 'each'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in 'block in require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in 'each'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in 'require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in 'require' 
>     from C:/Users/red19_000/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in 'require'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in 'block in server'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'tap'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in 'server'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in 'run_command!'
>     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in '<top (required)>'
>     from bin/rails:4:in 'require'
>     from bin/rails:4:in '<main>'
> ```
>
> C:\Users\red19_000\Sites\simple_cms>

Comment: Looks like you have a load of stuff which is needed, but isn't included.  What's your actual question?

Comment: Strangely reminiscent of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416013, asked earlier today. I don't really get the fetish for posting a great, dirty lump of log when the relevant bit is right at the top: "cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)"

Comment: What exactly would you like help with? What should your program do? What isn't working? Please also include the relevant source code that you were working on.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. Frankly, I dont know anything more than I am trying to boot webrick and receiving that flow of errors, possibly just the one as MarsAtomic stated. I have no direct intention right now as far as a specific program goes aside from what the tutorial is teaching me.

Comment: Have you considered following the breadcrumb trail I pointed to by including the related question? Click the link in my previous comment. Read it. Read its comments. Click subsequent links that you find.

Comment: MarsAtomic, I do appreciate the help. Still finding my way around here as well. It seems that it may be an issue with the newest version from what some are saying so i'm going to reevaluate the situation and start the tutorial over. Thank you for your time

Comment: As a follow-up to the current situation, moving back down to 4.0.0 corrected the issue